# Debugging a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to filter the following table so that I only keep the marker IDs if the P-value is below a certain figure in R , I want to keep all the rows. I need to apply this function to multiple files.

```
Gene Pvalue MarkerID
ABC  0.82   A123,G7893
ASD  5e-100 Y7934,chr10_39482
TRE  4e-10  chr2:098343
DDG  1e-04  LGT039, 10_39843
```

Into this if the threshold if 2e-06

```
Gene Pvalue MarkerID
ABC  0.82   0
ASD  5e-100 Y7934,chr10_39482
TRE  4e-10  chr2:098343
DDG  1e-04  0
```

I have tried:

```
filter_rows_by_value <- function(file){
 data <- fread(file)
 data$MarkerID <- ifelse(data$Pvalue < 2e-06, data$markerIDs,0)
 write.table(data,paste0(file,"_edited.txt"))
}

filter_rows_by_value("file_name.txt")
```

But I get an error:

```
"Error in file(file, ifelse(append,"a","w"): invalid description argument. In addition in if(file=="") file <- stdout() else if(is.charachter(file) {: the condition has length >1 and only the first elemnt will be used
```

If I run

```
`data$MarkerID <- ifelse(data$Pvalue < 2e-06, data$markerIDs,0)
```

as a line by itself it works fine`

Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like a typo. Rather than `write.table(data, paste0(data,"_edited.txt"))` I think you meant `write.table(data, paste0(file,"_edited.txt"))`. It doesn't make sense to use the data.frame itself in the file name.

Comment: thanks for that. Even with it edited, it now writes the file but does not run the ifelse function

Comment: Well, you seem to have another typo. In your function you wrote `ifelse(data$MarkerID < 2e-06, data$markerIDs,0)`. You are checking the `MarkerID` not the `Pvalue` columns. You wrote the `ifelse` expression correctly later in your question. Make sure you are suing the correct variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the spot, the actual code did not have this typo (i work in an airlocked environment on a HPC so have to manually type everything across)

Comment: If it didn't work then there is very likely another typo somewhere. Make sure you are looking at the right output files. With your current code, they will look like `file_name.txt_edited.txt`